# Get script file outside of vue2 scope

Tags: javascript, scope, vuejs2, vue-component, adblock

I need to detect if adblocker is being used on my site, from googling around the most common method of checking this is to create a ads.js or adverts.js file and then display a message if that has been blocked.

This file has been set up however I am having trouble accessing this file when it needs to be outside of the vue scope in a vue componenet, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to register independent js file's to the window object, then inside your component, you can call the object or function. For example, if your `ads.js` contain like as follow snippet

```
function block(){
 // console.log('i am gonnna show this ')
}
```

In your vue component

```
var newData = new Vue({

    el: '#app',
    data: {
        demo:'',         
    },

    methods: {
        fetchData: function (data) {
            window.block()
        }
    },
    created: function () {
         window.block()
    }

})
```

Like above the code you can achieve.